# Deploying a node.js TCP server on heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku

I have created a TCP server that receives messages from a client(using TCP Client android app for testing purposes) using node.js. Is it possible to deploy this on heroku? 
Here is the code

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var net = require('net')
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000
var routes = require('./routes')

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options', {layout:false, pretty:true});
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

//ROUTES

app.get('/',routes.index);

var mainserver = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log('connected');
    socket.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data.toString());
    io.sockets.emit('dummy',data.toString());
    });

    });

mainserver.listen(1337, '192.168.1.108');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(port);
```

As you can see, I send tcp messages to port 1337 and an IP address which is assigned by router.

When i type localhost:5000 on my browser I get an html page which just console logs the message that server recieves from app(and later sends it to client using socket.io).

There are two ports being used here.

If this were to be deployed on heroku, how to replace the port numbers? Also how to replace the IP address?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can run on heroku as it is. The only port that is exposed to outside that you can use for the web server is assigned on `process.env.PORT`. Socket.io will have to use the same ports as the web server.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have come to the same conclusion as well . Do you know any other hosting service[other than heroku], where the code can run?

Comment: AWS and VPS services like Digital Ocean can run multiple ports on one host. Does it have to really listen on different port other than port 80? you can use websockets on heroku. Socket.io and Express will be able to listen on the same http server.

Comment: Forgive me, I am kind of new to node.js, so didn't really understand what you said. I have an electronic board, which sends [or atleast i hope to] tcp packets over the Internet to this node.js server. This data is received by the server and sent to a browser by http server. So i figure it needs two ports.
Coming to your advice: websockets between tcp and http server, could you guide me towards some source code to help me get started.